# Stereoscopic 3D app development

Tags: 3d, stereo-rendering

I want to create an application to visualize image pairs in stereoscopic 3D. I want it to have a cursor that can move left and right, but also in and out. I think the way to achieve this is to draw a cursor on top of each image and then draw the images on screen (which would be a 3D capable screen).

How do I create such an application?

The experience I have is console programming in C, C++, Python. And I once used GTK+ to create a windowed app.

I've searched around and my problem is that I don't know where to start learning.

More details:

This app is meant to run on windows (although it would be nice if I could made multi-platform)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* broad question. The basic way to do this is to generate 2 frames - one for each eye. You can do this using any modern 3D API from [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org) to [DirectX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663274(v=vs.85).aspx) to [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/), [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/), or DX12.

You'll need to understand things like interocular distance, [depth cues](http://www.eruptingmind.com/depth-perception-cues-other-forms-of-perception/), and [3D compositing](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-3d-compositing.htm).

You'll also need some way to allow the user to move the curser in and out, so you'll want to read up on various user interface, visual interface, and user experience (UI, VI, and UX, respectively) techniques.